# Size of all files of a certain extension in a directory tree

Tags: command-line

I want to know the size of file with .o extension (object file) in my Home folder.

I can find all the object files using

```
find . -name '*.o'
```

How can I now calculate total size of those files?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're looking for pipes (`|`). They are a way of connecting multiple commands and passing the output of one command as input to another. In this case, you want to pass all the file names you find as input to `du` (which calculates size). However, because `du` expects file names and the results of `find` are just a list of text (yes, the text consists of file names, but `du` can't know that, all it sees is text), you need to use something like `xargs` which will take each line of text, treat it as a file name and pass that to `du`. Putting all this together, we get:

```
find . -name "*.o" | xargs du -sch
```

- you should *always* quote the patterns you give to `find` (as I did above: `"*.o"`). If you don't, the shell will expand the `*.o` to the names of any matching files in the current directory. It worked in this case only because you had no matching files.
- The `-sch` flags for `du` are documented in `man du`:

  ```
  -c, --total
        produce a grand total
  -h, --human-readable
        print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
  -s, --summarize
        display only a total for each argument
  ```

Note, however, that this will fail for filenames containing whitespace. This is almost certainly not going to be an issue for object files, but in the future, if you also need to deal with spaces, use:

```
find . -name "*.o" -print0 | xargs -0 du -sch
```

The `-print0` makes `find` print NULL-separated lines and the `-0` makes `xargs` take such lines as input.

Alternatively, you can have `find` print the sizes itself and then sum them:

```
find . -name "*.o" -printf '%s\n' | awk '{c+=$1}END{print c}'
```

This will also get around the problem mentioned by @Serg in [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817045/how-to-use-nested-command/817054?noredirect=1#comment1237321_817057) where there are too many arguments and the command is broken into separate commands.

---

If you're using `bash` (you probably are), there's a simpler way:

```
shopt -s globstar 
du -sch **/*.o
```

The `shopt globstar` command makes `**` match all files and  or more subdirectories. After enabling it, `**/*.o` will match all files (and directories) whose name ends in `.o`, so we can pass that directly to `du`.

Note that, unlike the `find` approach, this won't match hidden files (those whose name starts with a `.`). To match those as well, do:

```
shopt -s dotglob globstar
du -sch **/*.o
```

Comment: There is a bit of a problem with the first one. There is such thing as MAXARGS . So there will be multiple iterations of `du` , and it will produce  multiple `total` lines. Here's example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23092752/

Comment: @Serg true. I added another option that avoids that.

Comment: Your first `shopt globstar` example leaves out the `-s`; I had to use `shopt -s globstar` similar to your second example.

Comment: @CrazyPyro d'oh! Sorry, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. `shopt OPTION` without an `-s` or a `-u` (or other option, see `help shopt`) just prints the current value of OPTION. You need `shopt -s OPTION` to turn one on and `shopt -u OPTION` to turn it off.

Comment: If I e.g. run this on a folder containing only two other folders, and add the totals together, I get a different result than if I run it on each of the subfolders and add the results together.

I would avoid this method as after a lot of testing the results appear inconsistent and routinely incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

Use `-exec`  flag to run `du` command  with  `;` ( meaning per each file)

```
find . -name "*.o" -exec du -b {} \; | awk '{total+=$1}END{print total}'
```

Sample output:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt"  -exec du -b {} \; | awk '{total+=$1}END{print total,"bytes" }'                                     
find: ‘./.cache/gvfs-burn’: Permission denied
find: ‘./.cache/unity’: Permission denied
852690242 bytes
```

`find` is recursive - meaning that it walks through all subdirectories. If you just want to get total of all `*.o` files in the current directory, just do

```
du -b -c *.o
```

Answer (score 0):

with perl:

```
perl -le 'map { $sum += -s } @ARGV; print $sum' -- *.pdf
```

Size of all non-hidden PDF files in current directory.

Comment: OK, but the OP is looking for `.o` files and they could be in subdirectories. You might also want to add a `}{` before `print $sum` to avoid printing the sum for every iteration. We only want the last one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
find . -name "*.o" | xargs du -sch
```

fails if there are spaces in the filenames.
This can be fixed with:

```
find . -name "*.o" -print0 | xargs -0 du -sch
```